# Align div to be beside <a href> tag

Tags: css, html, alignment, meteor-blaze

I have tried to get this simple thing aligned the proper way but still looking for a way out. My simple question is how to align the circle `<div class="circle active"></div>`, to be beside the name. right now, it is appearing at the top.

```
<h4 class="media-heading">
  {{#if equals 'status.active' 'true' }}
   <div class="circle active"></div> 
  {{else}}
   <div class="circle not-active"></div>
 {{/if}}<a href="/student/{{slug}}" target="_parent">{{firstname}} {{lastname}}  <small class="pull-right">{{ createAt}}<label><input type="checkbox" name="eachstudents" value="{{_id}}">Add to Module</label></small></a></h4>
```

Comment: how about using `span`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `<div>` is a `block` level element.

You could either:

1. use a `<span>` element instead of the `<div>`
2. give your `<div>` a `display: inline-block` property

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot now. Appreciate

Answer (score 1):

apply `display: inline-block` or `float: left` to the circle class with css. Should work out fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for but I suggest two different solutions.

1. You can put the `div` and the `a` (link) in an `ul` (unordered list) and apply the CSS attribute `float: left`. You can then style it however you want to (by removing the bullets or something else).
2. Make the position attribute of the tags `absolute` and align them however you want to. This is not stable when changing the size of the window but you can give it a try.